# Jenkins Pipelines downloading tools

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

So I am using a Jenkins Pipeline to build some infrastructure with terraform on a slave. I then need to run some regression tests so I launch an on-demand cloud slave that can run these tests (the cloud slave has access to internal DNS and sits inside an appropriate subnet).

The new cloud slave requires maven, normally on a slave you just add the tools locations and as the slave starts it copies the tools from either the internet or from the master Jenkins server.

The cloud server failed to do this which I have seem before but I have never been able to figure out why some cloud slaves fail on the internet download and then go off and find the tools on the master and move them over and other just fail on the internet download and give up.

```
node(project + '-' + environment + '-' + 'od-slave') {
        def mvnHome = tool 'maven3.3.9'
        sh 'BASE_URL=${BASE_URL} ${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install'

        publishHTML(target: [
            reportName : 'Regression Test Results',
            reportDir:   'target/surefire-reports',
            reportFiles: 'index.html',
            keepAll:     true,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            allowMissing: false
        ])
    }
```

It might be worth clarifying that the pipeline is running on an always up slave and then switches to the cloud slave just to run the section above.

Any tips on getting the tools (maven) on the cloud slave that does not have access to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

So if I use this method to run maven, it fails then downloads the maven tool from the master:

```
node(project + '-' + environment + '-' + 'od-slave') {
    withMaven(maven: mavenname) {
        sh 'BASE_URL=${BASE_URL} mvn clean install'
    }

    publishHTML(target: [
        reportName : 'Regression Test Results',
        reportDir:   'target/surefire-reports',
        reportFiles: 'index.html',
        keepAll:     true,
        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
        allowMissing: false
    ])
}
```